# setInterval cannot clear with mouseup

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, mouseup

I am using mousedown and mouseup to trigger a setInterval function like so:

```
$("#rotateRight").mousedown(function() {
    intervalIRight = setInterval(rotateRight, 0);
}).mouseup(function() {
    clearInterval(intervalIRight);
});
```

This works great, however, if I release the mouse (mouseup) when I am not hovering over `$("#rotateRight")` then there is technically no 'mouseup' so the interval goes on forever and is never cleared.

I cannot use hover because I want the even to be when a user clicks and holds a mouse. But at the same time, I need to fix this 'mouseup bug.' Any ideas?

UPDATE: New code is as follows, but still does not clear interval because mouseup happens on an iframe, not the DOM.

```
var intervalIRight;
var intervalILeft;


$("#rotateRight").on('mousedown', function() {
    intervalIRight = setInterval(rotateRight, 0);
});

$("#rotateLeft").on('mousedown', function() {
     intervalILeft = setInterval(rotateLeft, 0);
});

$(document).on('mouseup', function() {
    clearInterval(intervalIRight);
    clearInterval(intervalILeft);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

clear the interval on any `mouseup` by attaching the event handler to the document.

```
var intervalIRight;

$("#rotateRight").on('mousedown', function() {
    intervalIRight = setInterval(rotateRight, 0);
});

$(document).on('mouseup', function() {
    clearInterval(intervalIRight);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xLAtM/2/)

Comment: I just updated my code above to reflect your answer, but it still does not clear!

Comment: It isnt registering a  mouseup because $("#rotateRight") is on top of an iframe, and i suppose the iframe isnt considered a part of the document?

Comment: I added a working fiddle, but if it the element is inside an iframe, that would be a different document, and you would have to target that then.

Comment: thanks for the example, yes the element would be the iframe itself. SO if a user drags there mouse form the button to the iframe, it continues rotating. Can I target the iframe?

Comment: You can always try targeting window, and yes, you can probably target the iFrame as well.

Comment: Targeting both window and iframe does not do anything when mnousing up over the iframe. Very strange. No alert either.

Comment: That seems like a strange problem indeed. I would probably try to isolate the problem, create a small fiddle, and ask a new question regarding that particular issue.